# How are these two topologies necessarily comparable?

Tags: general-topology

My friend and I are currently stuck on the following problem from Munkres' topology text. Not homework, but would still prefer no "spoilers", so to speak, unless necessary:

> Let *X* and *X'* denote a single set in the topologies *T* and *T'*, respectively; let *Y* and *Y'* denote a single set in the topologies *U* and *U'*, respectively. Assume these sets are nonempty.
>
> Show that if $T' \supset T$ and $U' \supset U$ then the product topology on $X' \times Y'$ is finer than the product topology on $X \times Y$

Consider the following:
$$T = \{\emptyset , \{0\}, \{0, 1\} \}$$
$$T' = \{\emptyset , \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0, 1\} \}$$
$$X = \{0\}$$
$$X' = \{1\}$$
Wouldn't this satisfy the criteria but lead to product topologies which are incomparable regardless of our choice of *Y* and *Y'*?

Comment: Your example does not match the hypotheses of the theorem, which require that $X=X'$ and that $T$ and $T'$ be topologies on this set. Your $X$ and $X'$ are not the same set, and $T$ and $T'$ are not topologies on either of your sets, but rather on $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott OH! Because of the "respectively" I read this as equivalent to "let X in T and X' in T'". If they are the same set this makes much more sense :)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If you make that an answer I'll happily accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Done. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not match the hypotheses of the theorem, which require that $X=X'$ and that $T$ and $T'$ be topologies on this set. Your $X$ and $X'$ are not the same set, and $T$ and $T'$ are not topologies on either of your sets, but rather on $\{0,1\}$.